# How to add multiple categories in function WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Wordpress - functions.php

I'm using this function to automatically add custom structure in url for posts in a specific categorie.

But now I would like to know how I could add multiple categories without having to copy this function over and over.

Other solution could be to have this function work for the parent post category and all child categories.

```
// url structure

add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the category for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "b" ) {
        $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/questions/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'b/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=b&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
    );
}
```

Comment: use a for loop?

Comment: Permalink structure for posts is: domain.com/post-name but for some categories I need the structure to be: domain.com/questions/post-name

Comment: can you add an `if` statement to distinguish between the two types?

Comment: Well just noticed the code isnt working after all. It shows a 404 for affected posts. So need to work on that first before I can adjust for adding more categories.